# How to deserialize unwrapped json with Jackson?

Tags: java, jackson

I am using jackson for during JSON to java.It works fine normally.

However, I have a questions.

Most of my json will contain common fields like status and description along with few changing fields.

i was thinking of putting the common fields into a separate class and including its object into all classes but it does not work that way as Jackson was not able to understnad that these two fields need to be set in other object.

```
Class login {
    private String name;
    private Response response;
    /* getters and setters*/
}

Class Response {
    private String status;
    private string description;
    /* getters and setters*/
}
```

This will not work for json

```
{
    "name": "",
    "status": "",
    "description": ""
}
```

Kindly suggest the best way to achieve it.I can think of only inheritance to acchieve it.

Comment: Thanks Conner.. Just to mention I will not like to use my own Objectmapper as i would have to do for all classes then.

Comment: just looking a way how to handle the json to java for {name:"" , status:"", description:""} by using two classes.. So i dont have to add status and description into each  response class

Answer (score 2):

Change your json like the following:

```
{
    "name": "",
    "response": {
        "status": "",
        "description": ""
    }
}
```

or if you cannot change `JSON` then change your class:

```
abstract class Response  
{  
  private String status;
  private String description;
}  


class Login extends Response  
{  
  private String name;
}
```

The code you have now will only work if you change the json to the one I wrote above.

Comment: Thanks Meda. I wish i can. I am comsuming the response and can not change it.  but i liked the suggestion.Ideally the service should have been coded this way.

Comment: I might be looking for a solution which might not be possible without inheritance or custome mapper.. but would like to discuss

Comment: @Smiles Ok I updated, this is not tested, I am more of a GSON user, if it does not work try to make them public

Comment: Thanks Meda.. I think they will work with default/public type.. Is there any other way to do ti or we can do it through only inheritance as suggested by you

Comment: may I know why `abstract class Response` and not `class Response` . What extra privilege has `abstract`  has here? Is it only because you would like to declare the getter and setter methods of the `status` and `description `fields in the subclass [`Login`] rather than in the superclass [`Response`]?

Comment: @Kiran you can still put getter and setters in the abstract class,

Comment: I think abstract because no one will be able to instantiate the class or convert a son into that class object.thus securing the point that it can not exist on its own